# couldnot access ssh on port 22, while opening terminal using browser front-end

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am accessing google cloud instance terminal using browser front-end, but it is not opening. It gets struck on transferring ssh keys and ends by giving the error "couldnot access ssh on port 22"

Comment: please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063885/google-cloud-virtual-machine-instance-created-from-snapshot-not-allowing-ssh/53121275#53121275

Answer (score 1):

Check whether port 22 is open in the firewall for that specific instance. You can follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to manage your firewall rules. You can try [connecting via serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) instead. The issue you are facing could arise due to many different reasons. It is worth trying different [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) steps for SSH connectivity.