# Locked out from a VM in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

We had a machine in google cloud which we connected to (via SSH) using our default project key.

The machine was up and working for a couple of days.
And now suddenly the server doesn't accept our key and we can't connect to it through the browser.

What can be done here? How can we regain access to our machine?

The VM is an Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: Double check the IP address that you are connecting to.

Comment: Adding to @JohnHanley's comment. If you have shut down your instance, it is possible that your IP may have changed if you're using an ephemeral IP address on your instance.

Comment: @hachemon I doubled checked the IP address. Also the SSH through the web interface doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would review is the IP address, if your GCE instance is using [ephemeral IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#ephemeraladdress) it may change if the instance is restarted.

Also, please try by accessing your GCE instance using [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh):

```
gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME --zone ZONE_NAME
```

If that doesn't work, force gcloud to recreate a new SSH key pair by moving the existing key pair:

```
mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine ~/.ssh/old-google_compute_engine
mv ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub ~/.ssh/old-google_compute_engine.pub
```

After this, execute the gcloud compute ssh command and see if you are able to access.

If you are using a 3rd party client, try to generate a new SSH key file:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
```

Then [add the new SSH key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) to your GCE instance and try the connection again.

Comment: It still shows the same error - "Server refused our key" when trying to connect using gcloud. I doubled check the IP so it's fine. I tried adding a new SSH key to the instance and it didn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried to review the [serial console logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output) to see if there is an internal firewall that is running within the GCE intance? In such case you should try to disable the internal firewall by running a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startupscriptrunninginstances) .

Comment: I checked it and there's no firewall. I've also tried using the startup script to replace the keys in .ssh/authorized_keys or even add a new user with a password.. Nothing worked so far

Comment: try this might . I have similar issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063885/google-cloud-virtual-machine-instance-created-from-snapshot-not-allowing-ssh/53121275#53121275

Comment: @FahadAbid Tried it.. Still didn't work.. I think that it can't even run the startup script :(

Comment: @Drxxd please share error of your serial port logs.