# All SSH is disabled when try clicking on SSH button in GCP -

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need help.  I do not know what I did. But for some reason I cannot connect via SSH through the web browser through GCP console....

Says Cannot connect to Port 22 SSH

I am wondering i anyone knows how to reset everything to  default (prolly firewall rules) so that I can connect via SSH again?

I have no issues creating Linux VMs.  Its just when I click on SSH button, it says Cannot connect. Screenshot provided.

Any help would be great! THANKS!

[image]

Comment: @JohnRiddick - you can connect to an instance without a public IP using Cloud IAP. However, that is not the solution to this problem.

Comment: 1) Do you have a firewall rule enabling port 22 to the instance? 2) Do you have Compute Engine Instance Admin? - needed to use SSH. 3) Did you enable `enable-oslogin`? - disable it reenable SSH login. 4) Are you connecting to the correct Public IP address? 5) Is your network blocking SSH connections? - some companies do block port 22.

Comment: did u connect using putty before ?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063885/google-cloud-virtual-machine-instance-created-from-snapshot-not-allowing-ssh/54401013#54401013

Comment: Thanks everyon

Thanks all for your assistance on this.  I was on vacation and missed responding to you.  I was able to get it fixed by just wacking all the FW rules.  Still didn't work after adding Port 22 to all instance (as a test w full full access) nope.   But then after 24 hrs it suddenly worked.  So I then backed off the permissions and locked it down and I am good now.