# Can't connect to instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm completely locked out of the vm.
I can't connect to serial and ssh gives publickey error. Any ideas how I can fix this?

What I tried:

- Set a startup script to create a new user with password
- Create another instance with a copy of the disk

Comment: Provide more details in your question about your instance, what you have tried (exact steps) and error messages. 1) Start by rebooting the instance. 2) Connect using the SSH button in the Google Cloud Console. 3) What error message are reported in Stackdriver. 4) Report these results.

Comment: also try to connect using gclod compute ssh comand with flag --log-http, this will provide more information on the error https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh

Comment: I already tried rebooting and using the button. Neither of them worked. I'll try to find the logs in stackdriver and using the flag.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/53121275/10981911 will be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can access my instance again. What I did is install the gcloud sdk on my pc and try to ssh into it that way. It succesfully created a new user and I could use it again.